# Windows Kerberos authentication and network protocols/ports

Tags: windows, active-directory, kerberos, spn, spnego

Got the following question. I have a windows forest A with a root domain A. A web server in domain A has a proper setup SPN. A user comes from another forest/domain, where a 2way transitive forest trust in in place. The user, from domain B logs on to a workplace in domain A. The forest where domain B belongs to can resolve the SPN to forest A, via the name suffix routing setup in the domains and trusts. Now, this all works fine. With wireshark I did some analysis of the authentication traffic flow between the web server and the domain controllers of domain B. I see traffic on port tcp/88 kerberos, getting all required tickets, I see some LDAP traffic udp/389, to validate the impersonation by ldap binding, but then I see rpc traffic, starting with a tcp port negotiation on tcp/135 (endpoint mapper), followed by communication on the ephemeral port region. Looking into the packets I see the originating machine name, but that's it. I also see krb5 information in this traffic, so assumably this is also kerberos 'related', allthough I expected traffic only on ldap (389) en kerberos (88). Can anyone shed a light on this how this exactly works? Is this some kinda Windows specific kerberos thingie? Thanks! Ronald

Comment: What service do you see mentioned on the port 135 capture? The traffic on the ephemeral port is definitely not Kerberos; it is Kerberos-*authenticated* MSRPC (DCE-RPC), with you seeing a ticket being sent as part of the AP-REQ or AP-REP there, but without knowing which service has been mapped to that port, impossible to answer for sure.

Answer (score -1):

Active Directory requires a truckload of ports. It's well documented.

https://serverfault.com/a/786356/20701

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/service-overview-and-network-port-requirements